# Django project eats memory

Tags: django, optimization, memory-management

I have a django project, and a problem - it eats a lot of memory and loads hosting too much.

How can I find the problem places in the project which eat a lot of memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for debugging/profiling, I suggest django-debug-toolbar as a starting location as well as the various tips in:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/

However this won't give memory usage info.  If you really need that, you can try some middleware using pympler to log memory usage while debugging and run the development server.

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/profiling-django-object-size-and-memory-usage-pympler/?c=1

I've found that doing this grinds my webapps to a near-halt and then there are the problems from using the dev-webserver (e.g., media files not getting served).

But as others said your best bet is to set `DEBUG=False`:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Django with `DEBUG = True` then Django logs every database query which can quickly mount up and use a substantial amount of memory.

If you're not running in DEBUG mode, then take a look at [gc](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html) module and in particular try adding `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)` to `settings.py`. This will show you a great deal of information about what objects are using memory.

Comment: Having debug on is definitly good way to make your memory fill quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Wilkinson stated this might have to do with the `DEBUG = True` setting. However it might also be important to know if you're running this project stand-alone or as a webserver.

A Django will automaticly cache querysets when opening a request and remove the references when the request returns. Since there are no requests in a stand-alone project the references are never delete and hence every queryset ever requested get saved.

To fix the stand-alone python issue simply call `django.db.reset_queries()` after you've done a bunch of request. This will allow the querysets to be garbage collected and fix your leak.